# Gradle plugin or any solution to package a jar file with selected artifacts

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a gradle plugin or a way to package a jar with selected set of class file(s) and selected set of dependency libraries in a java gradle project?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Are you looking at producing a fat jar with all your class files and those of the required libraries? Are you looking at producing an archive with your jar and its dependencies?

Comment: Let me give an example. I have 10 class files and 15 dependency jar files in the project. I would like to create a jar file with 3/10 classes and 5/15 dependency library jars.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Maven Plugin in your `build.gradle` file and config `uploadArchives` task.

example:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

dependencies {
    ...
}

group = "your.group"      // it is not necessary
version = "your.version"  // it is not necessary

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository (url: "file:///$buildDir/m2repo")
        }
    }
}
```

And then execute command `./gradlew :your-module:uploadArchives` or just  `./gradlew uploadArchives`. After executing task you can find your jar file in `build/libs` directory.

More information: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

Comment: How to specify the set of classes and libraries I'm looking for, but not all the classes and libraries in the project, like the example I mentioned in the question?  Kindly let me know.

Comment: @TechPassionate You can put your set of classes and libraries in a separate independent module (like a library) and connect this module to the main project. Then use `maven` plugin to your separate module.